# Serialize a List<object> to byte[] - c#

Tags: c#, serialization

as the title says, I'm trying to serialize a List into a byte[] to be able to send it through a zeromq socket.

First of all, what I'm trying to achieve is: get all the errors (from certain sources) from the Windows event log. Then, throw this inside an object, which has a list, and then serialize it and send it through a zeromq socket.

This are two classes I use to store my information

```
public class EventErrorList
{
    public int transmiter { get; set; }
    public List<EventEntry> events { get; set; }

}

public class EventEntry
{
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the code where I process the errors:

```
public static void Object(ref NetMQSocket response, string msgResponseCommand)

{

    try
    {
        EventLog myLog = new EventLog();
        myLog.Log = "Application";
        myLog.Source = "Application Error";
        var eventError = new EventErrorList();
        var listError = new List<EventEntry>();
        eventError.transmiter = ManagerDb.GetMachineId();


        for (int index = myLog.Entries.Count - 1; index > 0; index--)
        {
            var errLastEntry = myLog.Entries[index];
            if (errLastEntry.EntryType == EventLogEntryType.Error)
            {
                var appName = errLastEntry;

                if (errLastEntry.Source == ".NET Runtime" || errLastEntry.Source == "MSSQLSERVER" || errLastEntry.Source == "Service1")
                {
                    var entry = new EventEntry();

                    entry.msg = appName.Message;
                    entry.source = appName.Source;

                    listError.Add(entry);

                }

            }



        }
        eventError.events = listError;

        var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var mStream = new MemoryStream();
        binFormatter.Serialize(mStream, eventError);

        response.SendFrame(mStream.ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }


    }
```

Up until `eventError.events = listError;`, the code works great. But, from there, it is not working properly. I got this method of serialization from another thread in SO, but in the line `binFormatter.Serialize(mStream, eventError);` it is triggering the try/catch, and jumping into the exception.

This is the exception I'm getting:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in mscorlib.dll
```

I'm sorry if this is an obvious question, but I don't really code in c#, and I'm stuck with adding this functionality to an already existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark the classes with the `Serializable` attribute:

```
[Serializable]
public class EventErrorList
{
    public int transmiter { get; set; }
    public List<EventEntry> events { get; set; }

}
[Serializable]
public class EventEntry
{
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
}
```

For future reference you should read and post the error message as well:

> 'Type 'q48506847.EventErrorList' in Assembly 'q48506847, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' **is not marked as serializable**.'

Answer (score 0):

Adding a note here that since .NET 5.0, binary serialization is deprecated due to potential security vulnerabilities. See https://aka.ms/binaryformatter for details.

As a workaround, use `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` or an XML serializer.